# Couldn't pass the driver value in test annotated method

Tags: java, selenium, testng, screenshot

I have below code:

```java
@AfterMethod()
public static void takeSnapShot(WebDriver webdriver, String fileWithPath) throws Exception {
    // Convert web driver object to TakeScreenshot
    TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) webdriver);
    // Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file
    File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Move image file to new destination
    File DestFile = new File(fileWithPath);
    // Copy file at destination
    FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
}
```

I'm getting below error

> Can inject only one of `<ITestContext, XmlTest, Method, Object[], ITestResult>` into a @AfterMethod annotated takeSnapShot.

I couldn't pass the driver value which contains the value stored from another class.

Help me to solve this or with different solution.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? which line of code is triggering this message?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60666543/3092298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work in the way you are trying to do. TestNG automatically calls `@AfterMethod()` after each `@Test` annotated method.

What you need to do is to access driver instance in `@AfterMethod`. Store the driver instance in context variable from where you are initiating it and then access it.

Refer below code:

```
@BeforeMethod()
public static void setup(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "/Users/narendra.rajput/bulkpowders/bulk-powders/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.wego.com.my/hotels");
    context.setAttribute("driver", driver);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.print("ok");
}

@AfterMethod()
public static void screenShot(ITestContext context) {

    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) context.getAttribute("driver");
    System.out.print(driver.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

This is how you after method will be

```
@AfterMethod()
public static void screenShot(ITestContext context) {

    final String fileWithPath = "file_path";
    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) context.getAttribute("driver");
    TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver);
    File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File DestFile = new File(fileWithPath);
    FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
}
```